# Python, Tkinter: store content of Entry field into a variable

Tags: python, string, tkinter

Dear fellow programmers,

I use Python 2.7 on windows 10 64 bits.

I have an issue with a Tkinter window. In a parent program, I want to save a file and I ask the name of the file in a Tkinter window. My problem is that I don't succeed to get this name outside of the Tkinter window. Here is the Python code:

```
from Tkinter import *
globalFilename = ""    
class Master:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.filename = ""
        frame_e = Frame(top)
        frame_e.pack()
        self.t_filename = StringVar()

        entry = Entry(frame_e, textvariable=self.t_filename, bg="white")
        entry.pack()
        entry.focus_force()

        saveButton = Button(frame_e, text="Save", command=self.on_button)
        saveButton.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=S)


    def on_button(self):
        self.filename = self.t_filename.get()
        print self.filename
        root.quit()
        root.destroy()        


root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100+100+50")

M = Master(root)
print M.filename
root.mainloop( )
print M.filename
globalFilename = M.filename
print globalFilename
```

All print statements in this code give nothing when I enter any text into the Entry textbox. This is not what I expect. If I enter "test" I expect "test" to appear for each print statement (i. e. four times here). I tried to go everywhere on the Internet, I tried various tutorials, I tried to copy various examples, to follow various videos, I just don't succeed in fixing this issue.

*Note that this piece of code is embedded into a function called saveGame, which is used in a pygame loop.*

Thanks in advance! All the best!

Comment: The `print` statements that are run _after_ `root.mainloop()` do yield whatever I entered in the entry for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works.

The window is not drawn on the screen until you call `mainloop()`, so printing M.filename before that point prints an empty string (the initialization value). The `mainloop()` blocks until the window closes, after which 3 print statements successfully print the value that the user entered into the box.

You may be interested in the [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html#enterbox) module, which does exactly what your program does except you don't have to make it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as other posters told, the above code works in a vacuum. It did not work as embedded in my program because I initialized a duplicate tk() before calling my function and initialize it again. I removed this duplicate and it worked.